# Using AJAX's Tab Container in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabpanel, tabcontainer

I have a web-page application using ASP.NET written in C# that has a page where in it uses AJAX Control Toolkit - Tab container.

I used two tab panels that contain two gridviews. Tab Panel 1 gridview loads the detailed sales report while the other Tab panel is used to load the consolidated one. Both gridviews data source is from a different stored procedure. I need to have a print functionality on both gridview. When I click print button, The system should load the crystal report source based on what is the ACTIVE, or CURRENTLY SELECTED / CHOSEN TAB PANEL.

please see this

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" BorderColor="blue"  Width="100%" ScrollBars="Auto" Height="290px" BorderStyle="None" ActiveTabIndex="0"   >

           <asp:TabPanel ID="tabPanel1" runat="server"  >          <HeaderTemplate>Detailed</HeaderTemplate><ContentTemplate>

            <asp:GridView ID="grdDailySalesReport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                             BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" Font-Size="Smaller"
                              ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No records Found"
                              Width="140%" >

                        <Columns> </Columns>

                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"  />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#E6E6E6" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />


                </asp:GridView></ContentTemplate></asp:TabPanel> 






               <asp:TabPanel ID="tabPanel2" runat="server"  ><HeaderTemplate>Consolidated</HeaderTemplate><ContentTemplate>

                   <asp:GridView ID="grdDSRConso" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No records Found"
                                 BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4"  
                                ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Font-Size="Smaller" ><AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" width="100%" />


                   <Columns> </Columns>

<FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" /><HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" /><PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="Black"  /><RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" /><SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" /><SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" /><SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" /><SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" /><SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" /></asp:GridView></ContentTemplate></asp:TabPanel> 

             </asp:TabContainer>
```

I used the coding below to store a variable on what is the active tab panel, and send this to reporting page.

```
  protected void TabContainer1_ActiveTabChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                    if (TabContainer1.ActiveTab == tabPanel1)
                    {
                        txtSearchedLoc.Text = "Detailed";

                    }

                    if (TabContainer1.ActiveTab == tabPanel2)
                    {
                        txtSearchedLoc.Text = "Conso";

                    }
    }
```

It is not working.

Comment: Capitalizing "I" doesn't hurt.

Comment: sure, I will edit it for you, I hope you are not hurt.